# How to set alignment of text in cell of a dynamically generated table in ASP?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, html-table

I have the following table that I am working on. It is a dynamically generated table,

```
TableRow durationTableRow = new TableRow();
TableDuration.Rows.Add(durationTableRow);
for (durationCellCounter = 1; durationCellCounter <= durationCellCount; durationCellCounter++)
{
    if (durationCellCounter == 1)
    {
        TableCell durationTableCell = new TableCell();
        durationTableCell.Text = "Duration: ";
        durationTableRow.Cells.Add(durationTableCell);
    }
    else if (durationCellCounter == 2)
    {
        TableCell durationTableCell = new TableCell();
        string duration = years + "Y. " + months + "M. " + days + "D.";
        durationTableCell.Text = duration;
        durationTableRow.Cells.Add(durationTableCell);
    }
}
```

I want to right-align the value of duration string in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an align attribute to the cell.

```
durationTableCell.Attributes.Add("align", "right");
```

Or with css

```
<asp:Table ID="TableDuration" CssClass="rightAlign"></asp:Table>

<style>
    .rightAlign td {
        text-align: right;
    }
</style>
```